# loop.last of a certain block type

Tags: matrix, loop, block-types

What are I doing wrong here?

I'm setting block types 'stripCustom' and 'stripShowroom' to 'stripBlock'

```
{% set stripBlock = entry.contentImage.type(['stripCustom', 'stripShowroom']) %}
```

Then in a loop checking if 'stripBlock' is last and the current block is last but one.

```
<div class="section {% if loop.last == stripBlock and loop.revindex0 == 1 %}gutter-bottom--double{% endif %}">
....
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think you can compare loop.last to your stripBlock variable. I think loop.last just is or isn't.

Comment: Oh. So is there a way to test is a certain block type is last?

Comment: Did my answer below help you with your issue?

Comment: Haven't had a chance to look yet as I've been pulled away from that project, I will look today.

Answer (score 2):

To test if the current block is the last in the loop and of a certain type, you could do something like:

```
{% if loop.last and block.type == "yourBlockType" %}yes{% endif %}
```

or shorthand

```
{{ loop.last and block.type == "yourBlockType" ? 'yes' : 'no' }}
```

In the above example replace `'no'` with `''` to output nothing. It's  just there if you want to output something in case of false

or even shorter

```
{{ loop.last and block.type == "yourBlockType" ? 'yes' }}
```